# How to retrieve certain data in string?

Tags: php, html, curl

Hello may i know how to retrieve data in string?

```
$url = 'test url';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

echo 'Response: ';
echo gettype($response);
echo '<br>';

echo($response);
```

Output :

```
Response: string
TRANSACTION_ID=abc123
MERCHANT_ACC_NO=M213213
TXN_STATUS=A
TRAN_DATE=2020-07-20
CAPTURE_DATE=2020-07-20
SALES_DATE=2020-07-20 
RESPONSE_CODE=1
RESPONSE_MESSAGE=Success
```

As you can see the output of the code is as shown above. This is my first time to encounter this kind of output because usually I get json as the output. So my question is may I know how to retrieve the RESPONSE_MESSAGE in the output or may I know how to convert the output to array or json so that I can easily retrieve the data. Sorry for asking this I'm quite new with this PHP and CURL function.

Comment: Instead of `echo($response); ` Could you please try `echo '<pre>'; var_dump($response);` It will give you details along with data for the response.

Comment: Use `explode("\n", $response)` to split the string into an array at newline characters.

Comment: If the response is purely a string, then you can use `strstr()` function with `explode()`.
Like: `$message = explode("=",strstr($your_response_here, "RESPONSE_MESSAGE"))[1]`. It will give you the string contained in RESPONSE_MESSAGE.

Comment: hi thanks for replying AnkitSingh and Barmar. Actually i dont want to use the explode function but still its okay as long as i get the data and i think  i will go with Andreas method. Thanks again :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explode to lines and explode the lines to parts in a foreach.
Edit: I realized the "Response:" was actually outputted manually.
Changed the code to slice the array from second item instead.

```
foreach(array_slice(explode("\n", $str), 1) as $line){
    $temp = explode("=", $line);
    $res[$temp[0]] = $temp[1];
}
```

Output:

```
array(8) {
  ["TRANSACTION_ID"]=>
  string(6) "abc123"
  ["MERCHANT_ACC_NO"]=>
  string(7) "M213213"
  ["TXN_STATUS"]=>
  string(1) "A"
  ["TRAN_DATE"]=>
  string(10) "2020-07-20"
  ["CAPTURE_DATE"]=>
  string(10) "2020-07-20"
  ["SALES_DATE"]=>
  string(11) "2020-07-20 "
  ["RESPONSE_CODE"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["RESPONSE_MESSAGE"]=>
  string(7) "Success"
}
```

https://3v4l.org/evdMO

Comment: Wow sir, you really help me here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Giorno I see that there is an extra space in sales date, not sure if that is a copy paste error or what. But you can clean up such things by changing the line to `$res[$temp[0]] = trim($temp[1]);`

Comment: Thanks again @Andreas for your time you really help me out with my project. May god bless you :D